# How to add a UI to a large android listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an android app that displays a custom contact list of about 500 people and it works fine; however if I am looking for a name that starts with the letter "s", then it takes forever to scroll down.

How can I program it to jump to S without scrolling the entire list?

Here is the xml layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:background="@color/background"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <ListView android="@+id/android:thelist" android:layout_height="0dip" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:scrollbars="vertical"
  android:fadingEdge="vertical"
  android:padding="2dp" 
  android:fastScrollEnabled="true">
  </ListView>

<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/label" 
android:textSize="14dip" 
android:textStyle="bold" android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:paddingTop="3dip"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the fastScroll option?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:fastScrollEnabled

Comment: I added the fastScrollEnabled, but either it didn't work or don't know how to use it in the emulator.

Comment: When enabled, a _little thingie_ will appear on the right hand side of your list while scrolling. You can then grab this and fast scroll with it.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't appear, I get the little scrollbar that was there before, but the fastScrollEnabled is suppose to display a thumb box to scroll with.

Comment: If I add android:fastScrollEnabled="true" to the definition of a ListView, the thumb box appears as soon as I start scrolling. Please show some code if it does not appear.

Comment: I have added my xml layout file above.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out, in the emulator you have to hold down the mouse for the thumb scroll to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

1. Enable fast scrolling using `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"`
2. Ensure that your `ListAdapter` implements the interface `android.widget.SectionIndexer`

It's generally easy to implement `SectionIndexer`. An outline of the code can be as follows:

```
class SI extends ... implements SectionIndexer
{
   getSection() {
      return new String[] { "A", "B", ... };
   }

   getSectionForPosition(position) {
      //Just an example
      Object obj = getItem(position);
      char c = obj.toString().charAt(0);
      return (c - 'A');
   }

   getPositionForSection(section) {
      List<?> items = getAllItems();
      char c = (char) ('A' + section);
      int position = getFirstItemStartingWith(items, c);
      return position;
   }
}
```

Let me know if it worked.

-Gaurav
[www.incoleg.com](http://www.incoleg.com)